# Tornado how to download a file?

Tags: python, http, tornado

i'm writing some kind of caching proxy-server with Python and Tornado, and i need to download different kinds of files from remote server, i use `AsyncHTTPClient` with callbacks to do it, and it works great on images, but when it comes to video or 3d models - callback function receives empty `request.body`, what am i doing wrong? My code looks like this:

```
def test_callback(self, response):
    print response.body

def get(self):
    client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
    client.fetch(remote_url, self.test_callback)
```

And it prints None, when i download video or 3d model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because there is an error in the request or the request is timing out, so I'd suggest that you try the following:

```
def test_callback(self, response):
    if response.error:
        print("Error:", response.error)
    else:
        print(response.body)
```

This should give you more information. However, I think this is because the request keeps timing out. So, I'd suggest setting the `connect_timeout` and the `request_timeout` arguments in `AsynHTTPClient` to `None`.

Comment: Thank you, it really was timeout error, but i think this error appears because of the file size, it just doesn't completely download at the time, is it OK to set `connect_timeout` and `request_timeout` to `None` in such case?

Comment: Yup, there really isn't any other way. Also, you might want to use `CurlAsyncHTTPClient` instead of the normal `AsyncHTTPClient`.

Comment: I've made a liitle research and found out, that on Tornado 4.2.1 setting `connect_timeout` and `request_timeout` to `None` doesn't work, but setting it to somewhat big, like 3600 seconds (1 hour) works fine.